# how to use AWK to print between dates

Tags: awk, sed

My file contains the information like shown in the example . From this file I need to print just the date ,time and connection count  in row and get it exported to .csv  format.

```
      03/10/17 08:19:32  Timer-10  INFO:
      Current Connection Pool Statistics
      Total Connections Count       : 88 (Highest=92)
      Connections Closed Count      : 30473
      Available Connections Count   : 10
      Borrowed Connections Count    : 78
      Connections Created Count     : 30561
      Remaining Pool Capacity Count : 712 (Lowest=708
      03/10/17 08:19:32  Timer-11  INFO:
      Current Connection Pool Statistics
      Total Connections Count       : 10 (Highest=10)
      Connections Closed Count      : 19174
      Available Connections Count   : 10
      Borrowed Connections Count    : 0
      Connections Created Count     : 19184
      Remaining Pool Capacity Count : 590 (Lowest=590)
```

Output expected is as :

```
       Date                   TotalConnection Count    Closed ConnectionCount
  03/10/17 08:19:32  Timer-10    88                      30473
  03/10/17 08:19:32  Timer-11    10                      19174
```

Any help on this is appreciated

Thank you
SKM

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  What have you tried? Where are you having problems?  Where does the 'date range' implied by the question title come into it?  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You have shown input and desired output, which is good; you've not shown where you're having problems.  (The date format will make date ranges harder than if you had the ISO 8601-style format 2017-03-10 for the dates.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '/Timer-[0-9]+/{s = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
      /Total Connections/{ s = s OFS $(NF-1)}
     /Connections Closed/{ print s, $NF}' file

03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-10 88 30473
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-11 10 19174
```

> From this file I need to print just the date ,time and connection
>   count in row and get it exported to .csv format.

Just set `-v OFS=','` in `awk` will produce :

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '
   /Timer-[0-9]+/{s = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
   /Total Connections/{ s = s OFS $(NF-1)}
   /Connections Closed/{ print s, $NF}' file

03/10/17,08:19:32,Timer-10,88,30473
03/10/17,08:19:32,Timer-11,10,19174
```

If you want to put header then add `print` statement inside `BEGIN` block like  below:

```
$ awk -v OFS=',' '
   BEGIN{
        print "date","time","timer","total_conn","conn_closed"
   }
   /Timer-[0-9]+/{s = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
  /Total Connections/{ s = s OFS $(NF-1)}
 /Connections Closed/{ print s, $NF}' file

date,time,timer,total_conn,conn_closed
03/10/17,08:19:32,Timer-10,88,30473
03/10/17,08:19:32,Timer-11,10,19174
```

Comment: It would be great if you can explain this     awk '/Timer-[0-9]+/{s = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 }
      /Total Connections/{ s = s OFS $(NF-1)}
     /Connections Closed/{ print s, $NF}'

Comment: @skm: if line with `timer-` found, then save field/column 1,2,3 in variable `s`, then if line with `total connections` found then add second last field `$(NF-1)` to `s`, `NF` gives total no of fields in row/record, and finally if line with `connections closed` found then print variable `s` and last field (`$NF`) of that line. `OFS` is output field separator

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for a second that your data is in `in.txt`, one thing you could do is the following:

1) try to get your data into a line-oriented format where each line has all the information you're going to need to process the line in isolation and each whitespace-delimited column has a fixed meaning.

```
 awk '/Timer/ {
    date = $1 ; time = $2 ; timer = $3 ; preamble = date " " time " " timer
 }
 /Total Connections/ {
    print preamble " total-connections " $5
 }
 /Closed Count/ {
    print preamble " closed-connections " $5
 }'
```

Here's the result of doing that:

```
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-10 total-connections 88
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-10 closed-connections 30473
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-11 total-connections 10
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-11 closed-connections 19174
```

You can then pipe your solution to another awk program that assembles it into a complete line for each date, time, timer combination

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    print "date time timer total closed"} {key = $1" "$2" "$3
}
/total-connections/ {
    total[key] = $5} /closed-connections/ {closed[key] = $5
} END {
    for (key in total) {print key " " total[key] " " closed[key]}
}'
```

and the output

```
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-10 88 30473
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-11 10 19174
```

putting it all together:

```
cat in.txt | awk '/Timer/ {date = $1 ; time = $2 ; timer = $3 ; preamble = date " " time " " timer} /Total Connections/ {print preamble " total-connections " $5} /Closed Count/ {print preamble " closed-connections " $5}' | awk 'BEGIN {print "date time timer total closed"} {key = $1" "$2" "$3} /total-connections/ {total[key] = $5} /closed-connections/ {closed[key] = $5} END {for (key in total) {print key " " total[key] " " closed[key]}}'
```

gives

```
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-10 88 30473
03/10/17 08:19:32 Timer-11 10 19174
```